Equivalences for $G$-regularity and $F$-regularity in measure theory
I am doing some exercises from my real analysis class and got stuck trying to prove the following equivalences:
Let $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:
a) $ A \in \mathcal{M} $.
b) There exists a sequence $ (F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of closed sets contained in $ A $ and a set $ Z $ of measure zero such that
$
A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n \cup Z.
$
c) There exists a sequence $ (G_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of open sets containing $A $ and a set $ H $ of measure zero such that
$
A = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n \setminus H.
$
I have already developed a proof for (a) $\implies$ (c), but got stuck trying to do (c) $\implies $(b). Here's what i got:
(a)$\implies$ (c):
$A$ is measurable. By $G$-regularity, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $G \supset A $ open s.t. $\mu (G\setminus A) < \epsilon$ .
Consider $G = \bigcap_n G_n $, then $G\subset G_n \implies G \setminus A \subset G_n \setminus A$.
Define $H = G\setminus A$ .
Therefore, $A =G\setminus (G\setminus A) = (\bigcap_n G_n) \setminus H$ and $\mu (H) = \mu (G\setminus A) = 0$
Here's my attempt at (c) $\implies$ (b):
Consider $G$ from previous case.
Define $F = G^{c}$, then  $ F = (\bigcap_n Gn)^{c} = \bigcup_n (G_n)^c $ from De
As $G_n$ open for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(G_n)^c = F$ closed.
Here I got stuck, I can't think of a way to build $A$ that satisfies what I'm being asked. I had done a proof using $F$-regularity, but I would be doing (a) $\implies$ (b). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
-L

Can you clarify some of your terminology and notations? What is $\mathcal{M}$? Is $G$-regularity just outer and inner regularity of the measure?

Sorry, I never answered. $\mathcal{M}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, and I don't really know what is outer and inner regularity. But I could already solve it, thanks anyway. Should I post it? New here, don't know how things work in this case.

So, my answer was almost right, but instead of choosing $G = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n$ by $G$-regularity, choose $G_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by $G$-regularity. Let me develop:

(a) $\implies$ (c)

$A$ measurable. By $G$-regularity, $(\forall \epsilon > 0)  (\exists G_n \supset A)$ such that $\mu(G_n \setminus A) $ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Consider $G = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n $. It follows that $G\subset G_n \implies G \setminus A \subset G_n \setminus A$.
Define $H = G\setminus A$ .
Therefore, $A =G\setminus (G\setminus A) = (\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n) \setminus H$, and $\mu (H) = \mu (G\setminus A) = 0$ as desired.

(c) $\implies$ (b):

Consider $G_n$ from previous proof.
Define $F_n = G_n^{c}$, and $ F = G^c = (\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Gn)^{c} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (G_n)^c = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n $
As $G_n$ open, then $(G_n)^c = F_n$ closed $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Since $A = G \setminus H $, then $ A = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n  \cap H^c 
= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n^c \cup H 
= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n \cup H$

(b) $\implies $ (a)

Consider $F_n$ from previous proof.
Since each $F_n$ is closed, then $F_N \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Since $F $ is countable  union of  closed sets, then $F \in \mathcal{M}$.
Therefore, $A \in \mathcal{M}$ as $A = F \cup H$ union of measurable sets.
QED
